# How do I set my WebView font to the current typeface of the device?

Tags: android, webview, android-typeface

Yeah, I've seen a lot of how to use custom font using CSS, but I do not want this. I have an app with a WebView and the whole app has the device font, but the WebView has the default font for WebViews, and it seems kind of ugly.

I can get the default TypeFace with:

```
Typeface.defaultFromStyle(R.style.YourTheme);
```

But how is it possible to set it to the WebView? Or what way is better to get current device's TypeFace and set it to the WebView? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is local (in you device) just need to put the CSS file and reference like you do normally.

```
<title>Titulo de la web</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
```

Remember put the html file and CSS in assets directory.

Comment: Hola, Jose. What I want to change is the font of the WebView, and set it to the current font of the device.

Comment: The document you load in webview is yours?

Comment: The HTML document is online.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code for changing font on WebView and its working for me

```
data_webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.dataload_wv);
String custome_style = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: 
MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/font/roboto.ttf\")}body {font-family: 
MyFont;font-size: medium;text-align: justify;}</style></head><body>";
String pass_data = "</body></html>";
String finalString = custome_style + YourTxext + pass_data;
data_webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,finalString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: Presumably the `android_asset` fonts you refer to are fonts that you load into that folder?  This is no different to specifying a custom font stored at your host.  How do you specify a font that is already on the device, i.e. selectable as the system-wide default font and pre-installed on the device... that's not going to be in `android_asset`?